# Allow access to Firebase HTTPS functions from cross domain origin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I have implemented a https function with firebase which I can access from hosted web app inside the firebase but when I tried to access the function from other origin, I got cors error so I searched for the solution and finally I deployed my function with -

```
const express = require("express"),
functions = require("firebase-functions"),
app = express(),
cors = require("cors");

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: true,
  })
);
```

And it fixed the problem now I can access the function from any origin, even localhost so my question here is, Can I specify a URL only that can access my cloud function? Is there a way to restrict the function to be accessible from allowed origins?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a specific origin.

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com'
}

app.use(
  cors(corsOptions)
);
```

more info: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuring-cors

Comment: @B L Λ C K please accept this answer if it resolved your issue.